# Проблема навигации в Android

Tags: android, navigation

Использую Navigation в проекте.
С MainActivity я перешел на LoginFragment.

Теперь по нажатию на кнопку хочу сделать переход на TypeFragment, но у меня кидает с ошибкой

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton{c60b6af VFED..C.. ...P.... 376,828-704,924 #7f080098 app:id/btn_registration} does not have a NavController set
```

Что я делаю не так?
Как вызываю

```
btn_registration.setOnClickListener { view -> findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment2_to_newTypeAccountFragment)}
```

Comment: view у Вас - это кнопка, на которую кликнул пользователь, для нее `findNavController` не может найти `NavController ` и кидает ошибку

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov https://github.com/terrakok/google-navigation-test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/terrakok/cicerone/gnavigation/DFragment.kt

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov https://github.com/terrakok/google-navigation-test/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_d.xml это связанный Layout

Comment: Да, давно не вспоминал, мог и ошибиться(
`findNavController`же надо у Navigation вызывать исходя из примера terrakok

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Android Studio помечает Navigation как не нужный, который можно удалить

Comment: @danilshick пробовали его оставить? Студия иногда предлагает убрать то, что убирать нельзя

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov ну конечно

Comment: передавайте не вью а фрагмент или активити findNavController(this)

Comment: @Cypher требует именно View